# Log4j - How to log specific exception into a separate file?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I'm using a java application with apache tomcat, if a specific camel exception occurs then need to log it into a separate log file.

For example, the running log **(app.log)**, if specific exception **(JMS-131)** occurs then need to log it into a separate log file **(excp.log)**

**log4j2 configuration**

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>        
        <RollingFile name="LogToRollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                     filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="OtherFile" fileName="logs/excp.log"
                     filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/excp-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.test" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToRollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <logger name="oracle.jms.AQjmsError" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="OtherFile"/>
    </logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**app.log**

```
org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer [] - Initiating transaction rollback on listener exception
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: JMS-131: Session is closed
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsError.throwIllegalStateEx(AQjmsError.java:514) ~[aqapi-12.2.0.1.0.jar:?]
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.checkSessionStarted(AQjmsSession.java:5521) ~[aqapi-12.2.0.1.0.jar:?]
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.getTransacted(AQjmsSession.java:1015) ~[aqapi-12.2.0.1.0.jar:?]
```

I've tried using filter, RegexFilter & routing appenders but nothing seems to work as expected. All I'm able to achieve was to exclude the specific exception from the log.

I'm very new to this & any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A Log4j [`Message`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message.html) is composed of:

- a format and some parameters, which are interpolated to give you a formatted message. In your case it is:

  ```
  Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
  ```
- an optional `Throwable` that is formatted similarly to `Throwable#printStackTrace()`:

  ```
  javax.jms.IllegalStateException: JMS-131: Session is closed
      at oracle.jms.AQjmsError.throwIllegalStateEx(AQjmsError.java:514) ~[aqapi-12.2.0.1.0.jar:?]
      at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.checkSessionStarted(AQjmsSession.java:5521) ~[aqapi-12.2.0.1.0.jar:?]
      at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.getTransacted(AQjmsSession.java:1015) ~[aqapi-12.2.0.1.0.jar:?]
  ```

The `RegexFilter` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter)) only matches the formatted (or unformatted) message. The throwable is not used by this filter or any other of the standard filters.

Fortunately Log4j Core is very extensible and writing a new filter is a couple dozen lines:

```java
@Plugin(name = "ThrowableMessageFilter", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = Filter.ELEMENT_TYPE)
public class ThrowableMessageFilter extends AbstractFilter {

    @PluginFactory
    public static ThrowableMessageFilter createFilter(@PluginAttribute("regex") final String regex,
            @PluginAttribute("onMatch") final Result onMatch, @PluginAttribute("onMismatch") final Result onMismatch) {
        if (regex == null) {
            LOGGER.error("A regular expression must be provided for ThrowableMessageFilter");
            return null;
        }
        return new ThrowableMessageFilter(Pattern.compile(regex), onMatch, onMismatch);
    }

    private final Pattern pattern;

    private ThrowableMessageFilter(final Pattern pattern, final Result onMatch, final Result onMismatch) {
        super(onMatch, onMismatch);
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    private Result filter(final String message) {
        if (message == null) {
            return onMismatch;
        }
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(message);
        return m.matches() ? onMatch : onMismatch;
    }

    @Override
    public Result filter(LogEvent event) {
        final Throwable t = event.getThrown();
        return t != null ? filter(t.getMessage()) : onMismatch;
    }
}
```

You can then use it as:

```xml
<Logger name="oracle.jms.AQjmsError" additivity="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="OtherFile">
    <ThrowableMessageFilter regex=".*JMS-131.*"
                            onMatch="ACCEPT"
                            onMismatch="DENY"/>
  </AppenderRef>
</Logger>
```

**Edit:** For a temporary solution you can also use `ScriptFilter` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#Script)). To use it you need:

- a scripting engine like [Nashorn](https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn), which was available up to JRE 14 and is available standalone for JRE 15+,
- add the scripting language used to the list of allowed languages by listing it in the system property `log4j2.scriptEnableLanguages` (e.g. by adding `-Dlog4j2.scriptEnableLanguages=javascript` to the JVM arguments),
- write a script to match your exception, e.g.:

  ```xml
  <ScriptFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY">
    <Script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
      var t = logEvent.getThrown();
      if (t != null) {
        var m = t.getMessage();
        m != null ? m.contains("JMS-131") : false;
      } else {
        false;
      }
    ]]></Script>
  </ScriptFilter>
  ```